# what software is available to install on my pi?

Tags: raspbian

I have had a Pi for sometime - but it has been sitting in a drawer.  Now, I am wondering what software I might be able to install on to it.

Where can I find a list of software I can download to my Pi?

Comment: This question cannot be answered. That's like asking, give me a list of all Software available for Windows. You can always find software for a particular usecase but I doubt anyone provides a list.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Note that this is likely an open ended question and thus a very bad fit for Stackexchange. If you can narrow it down to a way more specific question feel free to edit.

Answer (score 4):

As the comment says it is not possible to give a complete list.

However Raspbian is based on Debian.  Debian has an extensive package list which you can search at [Debian packages](https://packages.debian.org/en/).

If the package is in Debian it is likely to be in Raspbian.

Use the following command to update the local copy of the list of packages available in Raspbian.

`sudo apt-get update`

You can use the apt-cache search command to check that a particular package is available.

E.g.

```
$ apt-cache search gpio
ledmon - Enclosure LED Utilities
stm32flash - STM32 chip flashing utility using a serial bootloader
pigpio - Library for Raspberry Pi GPIO control
python-gpiozero - Simple API for controlling devices attached to a Pi's GPIO pins.
python-gpiozero-doc - Simple API for controlling devices attached to a Pi's GPIO pins.
python-pigpio - Python module which talks to the pigpio daemon (Python 2)
python-rpi.gpio - Python GPIO module for Raspberry Pi
python-w1thermsensor - Python w1 therm sensor module (Python 2)
python3-gpiozero - Simple API for controlling devices attached to a Pi's GPIO pins.
python3-pigpio - Python module which talks to the pigpio daemon (Python 3)
python3-rpi.gpio - Python 3 GPIO module for Raspberry Pi
python3-w1thermsensor - Python w1 therm sensor module (Python 3)
raspi-gpio - Dump the state of the BCM270x GPIOs
wiringpi - The wiringPi libraries, headers and gpio command
$
```

Use the apt-get install command to install a package (you will be told if the package is already installed.

E.g.

```
$ sudo apt-get install raspi-gpio
[sudo] password for john: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
raspi-gpio is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$
```

NOTE.  Do not download a package directly from Debian, always use the Raspbian repository.  Downloading from Debian is likely to get you a package built for the wrong CPU architecture which is a pretty sure way of breaking your system.